# Azure AD Connect single sign-on error with setup

Tags: azure-active-directory

Situation:

- windows server 2012 R2 AD with example.**local** as domain.
- Created DNS entry for example.somedomain.com
- Added example.somedomain.com to example.local, so that users can log in using username@example.somedomain.com

In azure I have added an AD for "example.onmicrosoft.com" and added a custom domain example.somedomain.com which has been verified.

I am trying out Azure AD Connect with the following:

- Password Synchronization
- 'Enable single sign on' (preview!)

However, when I manage to fill everything in and end up in the tab 'Single sign on' I get an error with "Cannot retrieve single sign on status."

After research it seems that there was a 'bug' in some version of Azure AD Connect. I have the latest version (1.1.380.0) and for testing purposes I simply disabled the firewall on the machine I am trying to install Azure AD Connect on so there won't be a problem with port 9090.

What could be causes for receiving that message? In the docs that I found it simply assumes that 'it works'.

Answer (score 1):

During configuration, Azure AD Connect needs to communicate with Service Endpoint on TCP port 9090. The URL of Service Endpoint is usually like https://*.msappproxy.net:9090/register.

If the outbound TCP port 9090 is blocked on the on-premises firewall, or the URL is blocked on the on-premises proxy server,  then you may get the following error in the screenshot below during Azure AD Connect configuration.

[image]

Also, by checking the log file named *trace-date-number*, which is located at: C:\Users\currentaccountname\AppData\Local\AADConnect, you can find the following error messages.

> [10:45:41.010] [  1] [INFO ] DiscoverAzureEndpoints
>   [PassthruAuthentication]:
>   ServiceEndpoint=**https://{0}.register.msappproxy.net:9090/register**,
>   AdalAuthority=https://login.windows.net/domainname.onmicrosoft.com,
>   AdalResource=https://proxy.cloudwebappproxy.net/registerapp.
>
> [10:45:41.439] [  1] [INFO ] DesktopSso: exception caught in
>   GetDesktopSsoStatus One or more errors occurred.. Skipping
>   configuration
>
> [10:45:41.440] [  1] [ERROR] Cannot retrieve single sign
>   on status.

To fix this issue, please ensure that the outbound **TCP port 9090** is allowed on the **on-premises firewall**, or the URL ***.register.msappproxy.net** is allowed on the **on-premises proxy server**.

Comment: This is exactly the results that I can see. However, the firewall on the virtual machine was turned off, and just to be sure the firewall on the hyper-v host as well.

What I can see is that the URL `https://**login.windows.net/<directory>.onmicrosoft.com` is not accessible (page not found) from both the machine and another unrelated machine.

`https://login.windows.net/` however is accessable without problems.

Comment: Please also check the on-premises firewall, which may block the outbound TCP port 9090.

Comment: In the end I did not manage to resolve this. The sysadmin made sure the firewall was not in the way, so something else was most likely the cause.  For us the most important part is the single user/pass that azure AD provides, which is something that works fine.The magic SSO would have been a nice bonus but it does not have my highest priority to get this to work. I will try again at a later time. The information about logs is useful, so thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at firewall logs, I can say that the latest version of AADConnect still wants to connect to *.msappproxy.net:9090.
So make sure that whatever proxy/firewall you use to access the internet is configured to permit this connection for the internal machine.